# O que é o HMAC?

Tags: segurança, terminologia, hash

Ao trabalhar em um projeto que usa `sha256` e chaves de segurança, me deparei com o termo *hmac*.

Eu ainda não sei bem a fundo do que se trata, e gostaria de entender um pouco mais.

Tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

- O que seria um HMAC?
- O HMAC tem alguma coisa a ver com o hash (md5, sha1, sha256)?
- Por que escuto sempre algo como *"cálculo do HMAC"*? O que seria esse *"cálculo"*?
- Ele tem alguma finalidade para segurança das informações? Se sim, cite exemplos.

E por último:

- Como se pronuncia? Eu sempre falo: "Agá-mequi"

Comment: Em inglês se pronuncia: "Reitch Mac" em IPA: heɪʧ mæk

Answer (score 24, accepted):

HMAC é uma sigla para [Hash-based Message Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)

> O que seria um HMAC?

Um HMAC é um tipo de MAC (código de autenticação de mensagem). Um MAC é um código que você pode adicionar ao final de uma mensagem para proteger a integridade da mensagem, garantindo que ela foi recebida pelo destinatário sem alterações acidentais ou maliciosas.

A maneira mais simples de tentar proteger a integridade de uma mensagem seria incluir um checksum no final. Isso protegeria contra modificações acidentais mas não protegeria contra modificações maliciosas, já que uma pessoa mal intencionada poderia recalcular o checksum para fazê-lo conferir com a mensagem modificada.

Para proteger contra modificações maliciosas podemos usar um MAC criptograficamente seguro. Esse MAC é tipo um checksum, mas ele também depende de uma chave secreta que só autor da mensagem tem, o que teoricamente impede um adversário de recalcular o MAC de uma mensagem modificada.

O HMAC é um [um algorítimo específico](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) para gerar um MAC criptograficamente seguro a partir de uma chave secreta e de uma mensagem qualquer. É melhor usar esse algoritmo do que reinventar a roda pois muitos algoritmos simples como `hash(chave + mensagem)` são vulneráveis a ataques criptográficos como o [ataque de extensão de tamanho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).

> O HMAC tem alguma coisa a ver com o hash (md5, sha1, sha256)?

Sim, o HMAC é um algoritmo geral que usa uma função de hash internamente. Essa função de hash pode ser qualquer hash criptográfico, como md5, sha1 ou sha256 e dependendo da função de hash que você usar você fica com uma versão diferente do HMAC (HMAC-MD5, HMAC-SHA1, HMAC-SHA256, etc).

> Por que escuto sempre algo como "cálculo do HMAC"? O que seria esse "cálculo"?

O HMAC é um algoritmo e esse cálculo é simplesmente a execução desse algoritmo. A grosso modo, a função HMAC é definida por

```
HMAC(K, m) =  hash(K1 + hash(K2 + m))
```

onde:

- `K` é a chave secreta
- `m` é a mensagem
- `hash` é a função de hash escolhida (md5, sha1, etc)
- `K1` e `K2` são chaves secretas derivadas da chave original `K`
- `+` é a operação de concatenação de strings.

Para mais detalhes, recomendo ler a [RFC 2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) ou o [artigo da Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Definition)

> Ele tem alguma finalidade para segurança das informações? Se sim, cite exemplos.

Um exemplo de uso de MAC é que um servidor web pode entregar cookies para os seus usuários que podem ser lidos mas não modificados (pois qualquer modificação no conteúdo invalidaria o MAC).

Comment: Ótimo, cara, muito bom... +1. Só faltou a pronúncia :>

Comment: Em português eu falaria "maqui" mesmo em vez de "méqui". Mas acho que tanto faz.

Comment: Ótima explicação!

Answer (score 12):

#### Uma breve introdução sobre Código de Autenticação de Mensagem (MAC¹):

Um código de autenticação de mensagem é uma informação usada para autenticar uma mensagem. Um algorítimo MAC recebe como parâmetro uma chave secreta (compartilhada somente com o destinatário) e a mensagem em sí que será autenticada, e retorna um código de autenticação de mensagem. **Este código é usado para verificar a integridade e autenticidade dos dados da mensagem**.

Como podemos ver na representação abaixo, o remetente da mensagem usa um algoritmo para gerar o MAC da mensagem a ser enviada usando a chave secreta. A mensagem e MAC são enviados para o destinatário. Ele em posse da chave secreta executa o mesmo algoritmo sobre a mensagem e verifica se o MAC gerado é igual ao enviado pelo rementente. Se eles são iguais, o destinatário pode assumir que a integridade e autenticidade da mensagem estão ok.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>**Representação de troca de informações usando código de autenticação de mensagem (MAC).** 
Adaptada de: [Message Authentication Code - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)
¹MAC = Message Authentication Code</sub>

#### O que é um HMAC - Hash-based Message Authentication Code?

É um tipo de código de autenticação de mensagem (MAC) envolvendo em sua construção uma função hash (H) criptográfica combinando com uma chave secreta.

**SHA-1, MD5** e outras funções hash criptográficas podem ser usadas no **cálculo do HMAC** e sua força criptográfica pode variar de acordo com a função hash utilizada.

Na definição [RFC 2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) é apresentada uma representação da função/cálculo HMAC, onde:

- H(·) é uma função hash criptográfica
- K é uma chave secreta preenchida com zeros extras à direita para entrada no bloco do tamanho da função hash , ou o hash da chave original se esta é maior que o tamanho do bloco
- m é a mensagem a ser autenticada
- ∥ denota concatenação
- ⊕ denota ou exclusivo (XOR)
- opad é o preenchimento externo (0x5c5c5c…5c5c), um bloco de comprimento constante hexadecimal)
- ipad é o preenchimento interno (0x363636…3636), um bloco de comprimento constante hexadecimal)

<sub>Descrição e representação obtida em: [HMAC – Wikipédia, a enciclopédia livre](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)</sub>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Exemplo real de utilização de HMAC:

Um caso de uso que tive experiência foi a **validação da autenticidade e integridade de notificações enviadas de um sistema de pagamento** para um sistema de e-commerce (utilizando HMAC-SHA1), referentes à status de transações (confirmações e cancelamentos de pagamentos de produtos).

Esta validação é importante para termos certeza que a resposta vem do sistema de pagamento e não é de um indivíduo com más intenções forjando um POST de confirmação de pagamento de uma transação, por exemplo. A chave secreta utilizada neste caso é a *API Key* fornecida pelo sistema de pagamento.

#### Como se pronuncia HMAC?

Nos primeiros segundos [deste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcmLVilowb8) e [este vídeo também](https://youtu.be/KglnT_KwO0M?t=1m24s) é possível ouvir a pronúncia do termo em inglês.

**Referências:**

- [RFC 2104 - HMAC: Keyed-Hashing for Message Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104)
- [Hash-based message authentication code - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)
- [Autenticador de mensagem – Wikipédia, a enciclopédia livre](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autenticador_de_mensagem)